# SQL select from generate_series, filtering by user_id removes series?

Tags: sql, join, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.2, generate-series

I have a complicated (to me) SQL query in postgresql 9.2.4 using generate_series and multiple joins. I need to sum the reps for all exercises on a particular day from the exercise table, and make sure that those exercises belong to workouts done by the current user. Finally I need to join that table to a series to display missing dates (using generate_series).

My thoughts were to select the series in the from clause and then left join the series to a subquery that had the results of an inner join between the exercises and workouts table. For example, I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT date_trunc('day', series.date)::date as date,
    sum(COALESCE(reps, 0)) OVER WIN,
    array_agg(workout_id) OVER WIN as ids     
FROM (
    select generate_series(-22, 0) + current_date as date
) series 
LEFT JOIN (
    exercises INNER JOIN workouts 
    ON exercises.workout_id = workouts.id
) 
ON series.date = exercises.created_at::date 
WINDOW 
   WIN AS (PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', series.date)::date)
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

This gives the following output:

```
    date    | sum |                           ids                           
------------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------
 2013-04-27 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-04-28 | 432 | {49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,38,37,36,36,36,36,35,34,33}
 2013-04-29 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-04-30 |  20 | {50}
 2013-05-01 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-02 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-03 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-04 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-05 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-06 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-07 |  40 | {51,51}
 2013-05-08 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-09 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-10 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-11 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-12 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-13 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-14 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-15 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-16 |  20 | {52}
 2013-05-17 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-18 |   0 | {NULL}
 2013-05-19 |   0 | {NULL}
(23 rows)
```

However, I want to filter by certain conditions:

```
WHERE workouts.user_id = 5
```

for example.

But if I put a WHERE clause into the query above with that condition, the output is like this:

```
    date    | sum |                           ids                           
------------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------
 2013-04-28 | 432 | {49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,38,37,36,36,36,36,35,34,33}
 2013-04-30 |  20 | {50}
 2013-05-07 |  40 | {51,51}
 2013-05-16 |  20 | {52}
(4 rows)
```

The series goes away.

How can I filter by user_id and keep the series? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of taking all the data from WORKOUTS table you can put this condition over there also as -

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT date_trunc('day', series.date)::date as date,
    sum(COALESCE(reps, 0)) OVER WIN,
    array_agg(workout_id) OVER WIN as ids     
FROM (
    select generate_series(-22, 0) + current_date as date
) series 
LEFT JOIN (
    exercises INNER JOIN (select * from workouts where user_id = 5) workout 
    ON exercises.workout_id = workouts.id
) 
ON series.date = exercises.created_at::date 
WINDOW 
   WIN AS (PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', series.date)::date)
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

I think this should give you the output what you are looking for.

Comment: Hey thanks, that worked. I also realized you can also add: AND workouts.user_id = 5 after the ON series.date = exercises.created_at::date portion of my original query. Maybe your sub-select is faster because it doesn't join all the workout data though?

Comment: @kwyoung11: The subquery shouldn't be faster, the query planner end up with the same plan.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a complicated (to me) SQL query ...

Indeed, you do. But it **doesn't have to be that way**:

```
SELECT s.day
      ,COALESCE(sum(w.reps), 0) AS sum_reps  -- assuming reps comes from workouts
      ,array_agg(e.workout_id)  AS ids
FROM   exercises e
JOIN   workouts  w ON w.id = e.workout_id AND w.user_id = 5
RIGHT  JOIN (
   SELECT now()::date + generate_series(-22, 0) AS day
   ) s ON s.day = e.created_at::date 
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

#### Major points:

- [`RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) is the reverse twin of `LEFT JOIN`. Since joins are applied left-to-right, you don't need parentheses this way.
- Never use the basic type and function name `date` as identifier. I substituted with `day`.
- **Update:** To avoid NULL in the result for the aggregate / window function `sum()` use an *outer* `COALESCE` like demonstrated below: `COALESCE(sum(reps), 0))`

  ```
  sum(COALESCE(reps, 0))
  ```
- You don't need to `date_trunc()` at all. It's a `date` to begin with:

  ```
  date_trunc('day', s.day)::date AS day
  ```
- Instead of the complicated and comparatively expensive combination od `DISTINCT` + window functions, you can just use a simple `GROUP BY` in this case.

### Aggregate functions and `COALESCE()`

There has been confusion with this in a number of questions recently.

Generally, `sum()` or other aggregate functions ignore **`NULL`** values. The result is the same as if the value wasn't there at all. However, there are a number of special cases. [The manual advises:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html)

> It should be noted that except for `count`, these functions return a
>   null value when no rows are selected. In particular, `sum` of no rows
>   returns null, not zero as one might expect, and `array_agg` returns null
>   rather than an empty array when there are no input rows. The `coalesce`
>   function can be used to substitute zero or an empty array for null
>   when necessary.

This demo should serve to clarify by demonstrating the corner cases:

- 1 table with no rows.
- 3 tables with 1 row holding (`NULL` / `0` / `1`)
- 3 tables with 2 row holding `NULL` and (`NULL` / `0` / `1`)

#### Test setup

```
-- no rows
CREATE TABLE t_empty (i int);
-- INSERT nothing

CREATE TABLE t_0 (i int);
CREATE TABLE t_1 (i int);
CREATE TABLE t_n (i int);

-- 1 row
INSERT INTO t_0 VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO t_1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO t_n VALUES (NULL);

CREATE TABLE t_0n (i int);
CREATE TABLE t_1n (i int);
CREATE TABLE t_nn (i int);

-- 2 rows
INSERT INTO t_0n VALUES (0),    (NULL);
INSERT INTO t_1n VALUES (1),    (NULL);
INSERT INTO t_nn VALUES (NULL), (NULL);
```

#### Query

```
SELECT 't_empty'           AS tbl
      ,count(*)            AS ct_all
      ,count(i)            AS ct_i
      ,sum(i)              AS simple_sum
      ,sum(COALESCE(i, 0)) AS inner_coalesce
      ,COALESCE(sum(i), 0) AS outer_coalesce
FROM   t_empty

UNION ALL
SELECT 't_0',  count(*), count(i)
      ,sum(i), sum(COALESCE(i, 0)), COALESCE(sum(i), 0) FROM t_0
UNION ALL
SELECT 't_1',  count(*), count(i)
      ,sum(i), sum(COALESCE(i, 0)), COALESCE(sum(i), 0) FROM t_1
UNION ALL
SELECT 't_n',  count(*), count(i)
      ,sum(i), sum(COALESCE(i, 0)), COALESCE(sum(i), 0) FROM t_n

UNION ALL
SELECT 't_0n', count(*), count(i)
      ,sum(i), sum(COALESCE(i, 0)), COALESCE(sum(i), 0) FROM t_0n
UNION ALL
SELECT 't_1n', count(*), count(i)
      ,sum(i), sum(COALESCE(i, 0)), COALESCE(sum(i), 0) FROM t_1n
UNION ALL
SELECT 't_nn', count(*), count(i)
      ,sum(i), sum(COALESCE(i, 0)), COALESCE(sum(i), 0) FROM t_nn;
```

#### Result

```
   tbl   | ct_all | ct_i | simple_sum | inner_coalesce | outer_coalesce
---------+--------+------+------------+----------------+----------------
 t_empty |      0 |    0 |     <NULL> |         <NULL> |              0
 t_0     |      1 |    1 |          0 |              0 |              0
 t_1     |      1 |    1 |          1 |              1 |              1
 t_n     |      1 |    0 |     <NULL> |              0 |              0
 t_0n    |      2 |    1 |          0 |              0 |              0
 t_1n    |      2 |    1 |          1 |              1 |              1
 t_nn    |      2 |    0 |     <NULL> |              0 |              0
```

[-> SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ab70c/4)

Ergo, my initial advice was sloppy. You may *need* `COALESCE` with `sum()`.
But if you do, use an **outer** `COALESCE`. The the inner `COALESCE` in your original query doesn't cover all corner cases and is rarely useful.

Comment: Thanks, I just got around to this. That all makes a lot of sense. I did need COALESCE though as I needed to have a 0 there.

Comment: @kwyoung11: I added a chapter to my answer to update according to your feedback and make a fine point clear.